# Mean in R by using mean()

Tags: r, mean, moving-average

Given is the data.frame "data" with one column containing numeric values. I now want to calculate the mean of the range from value 2 to value 10 only.

I tried to adress it like this

```
mean(data$pressure[2]:data$pressure[10])
```

but r just prints the single value of data$pressure[2], no mean in sight. The problem seems to be all about communicating to r, that the mean is supposed to cover a range, instead of a list.

As aimed-at example:

```
mean(1:4)
```

which calculates the mean of 1, 2, 3 and 4 perfectly (=2.5).

I would prefere to do this without using packages, just with the default functions of r.

Edit: By trying it with more numbers as input for the mean I noticed that the output is limited to six decimal places. Is there a way to increase the number of digits?

Comment: this is fairly confusing... but do you want `mean(data$pressure[2:10])`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
mean(data$pressure[2:20])
```

or if you mean to get the mean value of all values between `2` and `10`:

```
with(data, mean(pressure[pressure > 2 & pressure < 10]))
```

Comment: If this answers your question, you can press the green tick mark to the left of this answer. This signals the community that this question has been answered, and gets me some reputation.

Comment: By trying it with more numbers as input for the mean I noticed that the output is limited to six decimal places. Is there a way to increase the number of digits?

Comment: the digits aren't really limited, it's the output.  You can set `options(digits=20)` (for example) or to change the number of digits for a single value you can do `mval <- ...; print(mval,digits=20)`